# ¿Cómo paso parámetros entre formularios Webforms asp.net con http post o Cualquier método que no sea QueryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Necesito saber cómo pasar parámetros con http Post o algun otro método, pues ahora lo estoy haciendo con QueryString (concatenando detrás la url) y no quiero que salgan en la URL por seguridad.
Gracias!

Comment: Si el motivo es la seguridad, entonces pasar los valores por otro mecanismo no bastará, en ese caso lo único recomendable es la encriptación. ¿Puedes indicarnos un poco mas que tipo de información quieres pasar entre página y página?

Answer (score 2):

Rápidamente se me ocurren 2 opciones y puedes leer [este artículo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6c3yckfw.aspx) de MSDN:

1. Variables de aplicación.
2. Cookies.

*Variables de aplicación*:
En origen, dentro del método requerido debes ingresar:

```
Application["NOMBRE_DE_TU_VARIABLE_QUE_NO_NECESITAS_DECLARAR"] = "Xavier";
```

En tu página destino, cuando quieras obtener la variable desde el origen, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
string texto = Application["NOMBRE_DE_TU_VARIABLE_ASIGNADA_EN_ORIGEN"].ToString();
```

*Cookies*
Misma temática que la anterior, con la diferencia que lo almacenamos en las cookies, es decir, en el cliente.
En origen, dentro del método requerido debes ingresar:

```
HttpCookie strCookie = new HttpCookie("NOMBRE_DE_TU_VARIABLE_QUE_NO_NECESITAS_DECLARAR");
strCookie.Value = "Xavier";
```

En tu página destino, cuando quieras obtener la variable desde el origen, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
string name = Request.Cookies["NOMBRE_DE_TU_VARIABLE_ASIGNADA_EN_ORIGEN"].Value;
```

Existen otras formas de hacerlo pero con esto creo que es suficiente. Recuerda encriptar las cadenas que pasas por estos métodos.

Comment: Christian, su problema no tiene que ver con como pasar datos de una página a otra así diga eso en el título. El problema real es hacerlo de manera segura, las soluciones deberían atacar el problema de la encriptación, no el paso de parámetros. Me parece que este es un clásico [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: ¿Cómo paso parámetros entre formularios Webforms asp.net con http post o Cualquier método que no sea QueryString? es la pregunta...

Comment: Si pero ese no es el problema real, @Xavier ha preguntado por la forma en que está tratando de resolver el problema, es decir pasar los parámetros por la url, cuando en realidad su problema es pasar de manera segura valores entre páginas. Si se realiza mediante encriptación bien pueden pasar por querystring o por otros medios sin problemas. O quizás por ejemplo si se trata de no mostrar un id, se puede pasar un GUID por querystring en lugar del id real y asociar ese GUID a n registro en la BD. Sin más explicaciones de parte de Xavier, lo que menciono solo son especulaciones.

Comment: ¿Especulaciones? Su pregunta es clara. Simplemente menciona que no quiere pasar valores en la QueryString por seguridad, en ningún momento relaciona su pregunta con seguridad.

Comment: "... y no quiero que salgan en la URL por seguridad." - Eso es lo que menciona Xavier y ese es el problema real

Answer (score 2):

La forma mas simple de implementarlo se lo conoce como `Cross Page`

[Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139(v=vs.100).aspx)

Basicamente realizas un `post` a la otra pagina, pero usas el `Page.PreviousPage` para obtener los datos de los controles del otro form.

Tambien con la misma tecnica puedes definir propiedades que accedes mediente la definicion del `<%@ PreviousPageType`.

Para redireccionar a la otra pagina puedes usar el `PostBackUrl` o el `Server.Transfer()`

[Cómo: Pasar valores entre páginas Web ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: De este modo solo puedo coger valores de controles, pero no un valor de una variable ¿verdad?, o sea tiene que ser el valor de algun control por fuerza. ¿Y las variables de sesión?

Comment: Una variable no se conserva entre post por lo tanto no seria una tecnica valida, a menos que asignes ese valor a un control Hidden, de esta forma al realizar el post si pasaria al otro form, solo debes usar el FindControl() en el PreviousPage buscando ese control hidden. Puedes usar variables de Session pero en ese caso el valor no estaria pasando por post

Comment: Leandro, su problema no tiene que ver con como pasar datos de una página a otra así diga eso en el título. El problema real es hacerlo de manera segura, las soluciones deberían atacar el problema de la encriptación, no el paso de parámetros. Me parece que este es un clásico [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz pero pasarlo de forma segura es un tema del vinculo, para eso deberia implementar https creando un canal que use SSL. O sino que dejar el valor en el servidor en un objeto Session. Como en la pregunta menciona pasar datos por post y no verlos en la url imagine que era un tema de tecnica para pasar los datos entre paginas y no de seguridad.

Comment: Pero ninguno de los dos enlaces menciona https o encriptación. Además el otro problema es que deberías explicarlo en la respuesta y no dejar solo los enlaces.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz explicar que cosa ? implementar cross page son varios paso y se puede implementar de varias formas diferentes segun se quiera acceder al controles o a propiedades, seria practicamente escribir un articulo en un blog. Lo que hice fue mencionar algunos puntos especificos en la implementacion se podria ampliar si es que interesa conocer mas de la tecnica, pero explicarlo completo seria muy largo.

Comment: Pero si la pregunta es muy amplia, entonces no es muy útil escribir respuestas a esas preguntas. Lo que si sería útil es dejar como comentarios los enlaces si es que le sirven. Y no es necesario un gran artículo bastante largo sobre Cross Posting, basta con algunas líneas de código para guiarlo sobre el tema. Además dices que explicarlo completo sería muy largo, pero en otras preguntas varias personas se toman precisamente ese largo trabajo de explicar las cosas en sus respuestas.

Comment: Carlos Muñoz estás complicando mucho el tema. La pregunta de Xavier es cómo pasar parámetros sin usar QueryString y nada más. La pregunta es clara y nuestras respuestas también. No sé cual es el drama.

Answer (score 0):

Al final hemos optado por encriptar toda la parte del querystring de la url y desencriptarla al recogerla en el otro formulario. Pero he probado vuestras soluciones y también hubieran servido perfectamente ;-)

Comment: Solamente responde las preguntas cuando tengas una solución, para agregar información como en este caso, edita tu pregunta.